# create a project using Azure account

Tags: azure, google-cloud-automl, microsoft-custom-vision

As per this page, I can not upload more than 100,000 images using customvision ai console.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/limits-and-quotas

The tool-tip says: "If you need more quota, you should create a project using Azure account"

How do I create a project using Azure account to get more quota?

Comment: What is the limit for the service by google (automl vision)?